# get title of HTML document using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument, title

How do I get the title of an HTML document using DOMDocument? I realize that there are other similar questions on SO, but most of them are three years old, and I'm wondering if they are now obsolete.

Per other existing answers on SO, I am using the following code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
var_dump($title);
```

`$title` contains NULL for me.  Shouldn't it contain a string?  I have verified that `$html` does indeed contain the webpage's HTML.

Comment: I'm getting `string 'Stack Overflow' (length=14)` with your code. Are you getting the rest of the HTML? If not, check your setting of `allow_url_fopen.`.

Comment: @n-dru: Yep, the original code works for me as well.